# OS X El Capitan no sound output device found

Tags: macos, audio, soundflower

Every time I start my Mac, there's no output device listed in system preferences > audio. In order to fix this, I have to reset SMC several times. I also tried to reset NVRAM. However, if I turn off the Mac and start it again the next day, the same problem appears again.
This problem first occurred, after I installed soundflower. But I uninstalled it already.
I'm using Mac Mini late 2012 with common Logitech loudspeakers.

[image: There should be internal speakers and headphones listed]
[image]

When I run Apple Hardware test, it outputs this result:
`4hdd/11/40000000: Sata(0,0)`

[image]

Comment: A couple things...your "answer" should be put into the original question.  Just click "edit" and add the additional info in.  Secondly, run the test with the "Extended" option checked.  To verify your disk, download a copy of DriveDX (it's free) and get the SMART diagnostic info from the drive itself  http://binaryfruit.com/drivedx

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing I would do is run an Apple Hardware Test.

When you turn on the computer, before you hear the startup chime, press and hold the <kbd>D</kbd> key.

Also, there is one item to double check and that is if you uninstalled Soundflower completely.

Use an app like  [AppCleaner](http://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) to ensure that you've got everything associated with the app.  Best of all, it's free.